# jQuery load 3 divs from single page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently loading the same page 3 times with 3 different `.load()` calls. I am wanting to know if there is something I can do to `optimize` the code.

When I click a link currently it loads the page 3 times

```
$("#"+target).load(url + " #page", function(response, status, xhr){
  if(status === "error")
  {
    $("#"+target).load('error.php?error=503 #page', function(response, status, xhr){
      if(status === "error")
      {
        alert("Something has gone very wrong right now, please contact an admin quoting 'error.php'");
        return;
      }
    }); // This should never fail but if it does kill the page
    console.log('Content failed to load ' + xhr.status + ' ' + xhr.statusText);

    //Force update the title to error
    document.title = "Error";

    $("#pageBreadcrumbs").load('error.php #breadcrumbs');
  }
  else
  {
    console.log('Content was loaded');
    //Load the title dynamically
    document.title = "Venus | " + name;
    $("#pageBreadcrumbs").load(url + ' #breadcrumbs');

    if(sidebar === true)
      $("#pageSidebar").load(url + ' #sidebar');
  }
```

Is there anyway I can shorten this to just 1 call to the url or error page and extract it from there?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
$.get(url, function(response) {
    var $nodes = $(response);

    ... some conditions ...

    var $container1 = $("#"+target).html('');
    $nodes.find('#page').appendTo($container1);

    ... some conditions ...

    var $container2 = $("#pageBreadcrumbs").html('');
    $nodes.find('#breadcrumbs').appendTo($container2);
});
```

I'm not really sure that it works, but you can try it...

**UPDATE**

This code assumes that whole server response is wrapped in one container (div)

Comment: The pages that are being loaded are formatted as
`<div id="page"></div><div id="sidebar"></div>`

Comment: You can try to wrap these tags in one outer `div`